# How can I run a hadoop example jar in an oozie workflow?

Tags: unit-testing, hadoop

this is driving me nuts - I feel like an idiot trying to work out how to do this!

I'm building an app that uses the Oozie client libraries to run a workflow. Really simple, I would like to build some tests for my code, so I can check i'm doing the right thing the actual code - thanks to the oozie client library - is very simple.

I have installed Hadoop and can run the standard wordcount supplied example, with no problems, but I can't work out how to run stuff via Oozie and its driving me nuts.

So I figured I'd cheat and ask some people who will know (creep creep).

How do I convert:

```
bin/hadoop jar hadoop*examples*.jar wordcount input/somedata output
```

To an Oozie Workflow?

I assume its a Java action, but I just can't work out what to fill into the workflows xml!

please help - what would the workflow look like and how would I run it on the command line.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For running a Oozie Job you'll need workflow.xml and a properties file.
For running Basic WordCount Program your workflow.xml will be something like this.

```
<workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.1" name="WorkflowRunnerTest">

  <start to="intersection0"/>

  <action name="intersection0">
    <map-reduce>
      <job-tracker>localhost:54101</job-tracker>
      <name-node>hdfs://localhost:54100</name-node>

      <prepare>
        <delete path="hdfs://localhost:54100/user/user1/out1"/>
      </prepare>

      <configuration>
        <property> 
          <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
          <value>default</value>
        </property>
        <property>
          <name>mapred.mapper.class</name>
          <value>MapperClass</value>
        </property>
        <property>
          <name>mapred.reducer.class</name>
          <value>ReducerClass</value>
        </property>
        <property>
          <name>mapred.output.key.class</name>
          <value>org.apache.hadoop.io.Text</value>
        </property>
        <property>
          <name>mapred.output.value.class</name>
          <value>org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable</value>
        </property>
        <property>
          <name>mapred.input.dir</name>
          <value>/user/user1/inp</value>
        </property>
        <property>
          <name>mapred.output.dir</name>
          <value>/user/user1/out1</value>
        </property>
      </configuration>
    </map-reduce>

    <ok to="end"/>
    <error to="fail"/>
  </action>

  <kill name="fail">
    <message>Map/Reduce failed, error message</message>
  </kill>
  <end name="end"/>

</workflow-app>
```

job.propertis file will be
`oozie.wf.application.path=hdfs://localhost:54100/user/user1/oozie/workflow-apps/sample-mr`

The workflow.xml has to be present in hdfs://localhost:54100/user/user1/oozie/workflow-apps/sample-mr and **copy the jar** file containing the necessary class into the path  hdfs://localhost:54100/user/user1/oozie/workflow-apps/sample-mr/lib .
 

The Oozie job can be run from command line by

`oozie job -oozie http://localhost:8080/oozie -config map-reduce-job.properties -run`

Comment: Thanks, That works!
Is there an explicit way to specify jar file instead of copying to ${oozie.wf.application.path}/lib/ ?

( OR )
How do i use same JAR file for 2 different Workflows without duplicating it in HDFS?

Comment: @ThammeGowda ${oozie.wf.application.path}/lib/ can actually be a common path. The same path can be used for two workflows, so that you don't have to replicate your jars.e.g hdfs://localhost:54100/user/user1/oozie/lib can be the shared location for all the jars. This path will be set as oozie.libpath for the oozie job.